# Virtual IP in pacemaker cluster not pinging

Tags: linux, networking, cluster, pacemaker, virtual-ip

I have two Linux rhel8 servers with pacemaker/corosync/pcsd installed. I've used the ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 resource to create a virtual IP for the cluster.

I have a similar setup on a few older clusters and it works fine but the ones I'm setting up now won't ping from outside of the server.

The IP shows up on the server but won't ping.

```
# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.x.76.236/22 brd 10.x.79.255 scope global noprefixroute ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.x.75.117/32 scope global noprefixroute ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I tried adding a broadcast address too but that doesn't change anything as well.

I'm having the same issue with two such clusters and can't figure out what's wrong.

I'm not very well versed with networking so it'd be great if I can get any help on this.

Thanks,
Karan

Answer (score 0):

try to configure same subnet IP

Comment: That's not really an option since we need to get the IPs reserved first. so the only ones I could use are the ones provided.